# How to include linux/module.h in my source file?

Tags: c, linux, kernel, interrupt, c11

I have looked at other similar questions around stackoverflow, but it doesn't seem to work for me. I am trying to compile a code sample, and it needs these header files:

```
linux/module.h
linux/modversion.h
linux/sched.h
linux/tqueue.h
```

But I keep getting errors saying that those files can't be found. I know I should add them to the kernel, but can you please guide me through the process and tell me how to get this done. Thanks in advance for any help. 
The code sample can be found [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.4/html/x1210.html).

Comment: This seems to be a kernel module. Have you read about [compiling kernel modules](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x181.html)?

Comment: Have you done through chapter 2 in the tutorial you link to, so you know you have a proper environment for compiling a kernel module ? Do that and show us the output when you use the supplied makefile if it doesn't work.

Comment: Sou should add to you make file something like this **make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) modules**

Comment: Oh thank you both, I haven't checked that no!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to compile kernel source code first, or check if the below path exists

```
/lib/modules/kernel-version/build
```

Or more precisely

```
/lib/modules/`uname -r`/build
```

Or

```
path to your kernel build
```

This is generally the path where your kernel build tree is present.

Needless to say normal gcc based compilation wont work here.

[This should get you started](http://www.linuxchix.org/content/courses/kernel_hacking/lesson8)

Answer (score -1):

Some of these files are shipped with any linux distro in :

```
/usr/include/linux/
```

but if you haven't linux installed in your machine see linux source tree in github repo :

```
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/include/linux
```